# How do I access Environment Variables in a windows batch job?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to read login cridentials from the command prompt in order to execute a series of SQL*Loader Scripts.
I am able to see that the variable got set using **set v_**. However, I can't access the values.

Test File:

```
@echo off

set /P v_user = Username: 
set /P v_pass = Password: 
set /P v_db   = Database: 

ECHO Username: "%V_USER%"
ECHO Password: "%V_PASS%"
ECHO Database: "%V_DB%"

set v_

pause
```

Actual Result Result:

```
Username: 1    <-- Input
Password: 2    <-- Input
Database: 3    <-- Input
Username: ""  
Password: ""  
Database: ""  
v_db   =3  
v_pass =2  
v_user =1
```

Expected Result Result:

```
Username: 1    <-- Input
Password: 2    <-- Input
Database: 3    <-- Input
Username: "1"  
Password: "2"  
Database: "3"  
v_db   =3  
v_pass =2  
v_user =1
```

Intended Use:

```
@echo off

set /P v_user = Username: 
set /P v_pass = Password: 
set /P v_db   = Database: 

sqlldr %v_user%/%v_pass%@%v_db% CONTROL='TABLE_T1.ctl' log='logs/TABLE_T1.log' bad='bad/TABLE_T1.bad' skip=1
sqlldr %v_user%/%v_pass%@%v_db% CONTROL='TABLE_T2.ctl' log='logs/TABLE_T2.log' bad='bad/TABLE_T2.bad' skip=1

pause
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the `=` in the set statements:

```
echo off

set /P v_user=Username: 
set /P v_pass=Password: 
set /P v_db=Database: 

ECHO Username: "%V_USER%"
ECHO Password: "%V_PASS%"
ECHO Database: "%V_DB%"

set v_

pause
```

The other alternative is to change the ECHO statements to contain the same number of trailing spaces as the SET statement used between the variable name and `=` sign:

```
@echo off

set /P v_user = Username: 
set /P v_pass = Password: 
set /P v_db   = Database: 

ECHO Username: "%V_USER %"
ECHO Password: "%V_PASS %"
ECHO Database: "%V_DB   %"

set v_

pause
```

Comment: Thanks, Removing the spaces worked. I'm too used to java where spacing doesn't matter much.